# Any way to get a Brother HL-L2320D to work with current Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, brother

I have installed the Brother printer driver from their website using the specified terminal operations.  At the end of the install, the script offered to print a test page, and did so successfully.  However, no other printing can be done.  The printer is connected directly, not network.  The printer shows up in my Printers folder; it says it is my default printer, and is online, but clicking Print Test Page there does nothing.  Any suggestions, or should I give this (inexpensive monochrome laser) printer to someone running Windows and try again to buy something that might work with Ubuntu?

Comment: Show us "the specified terminal operations. At the end of the install, the script offered to print a test page, and did so". What did you actually do? Edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/966106/edit ) your post, cut-and-paste the commands nd their results, format with the `{}` tool. Otherwise, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: try http://127.0.0.1:631/

Answer (score 0):

I would delete the existing Brother icon in your PRINTERS folder; go here http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2320d_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625 and click to download and SAVE the brother installer tool and it should end up in your Downloads folder. Then copy the commands below and paste into a terminal; line by line

```
cd Downloads
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1 (1).1-1.gz
sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1 (1).1-1 HL-L2320D
```

and that should run the installer tool; it will ask you some questions; and it should work