# Brother printer only prints test page

Tags: printing, brother

The printer prints the test page...but when trying to print a non-test page the led on the printer blinks and Ubuntu gives me the message "Print completed" but no printing happens...

Can someone help ?

Comment: Are you connected to the printer by usb cable or is this a network printer?

Comment: Also, did you install the drivers from the brother website?

Comment: The USB cable is connected. I only plan to use this with my laptop. I tried everything but no luck..I installed the drivers as well...

Comment: Followed this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/966106/any-way-to-get-a-brother-hl-l2320d-to-work-with-current-ubuntu     The drivers are detected since the leds on the printer blink when i try to print something...in the driver settings page when I click the print test page the printer actually works bbut nothing else works

Comment: Maybe problem is not a printer, as you mentioned test page is working, which is showing that printer is just fine.
I have same problem as described in another post. PDFs just don't work for ptinting in default worthless viewer.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083319/cant-print-pdfs-under-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by removing the driver and then running:

```
apt-get purge cups   
apt-get install cups
```

Then I reinstalled the driver as instructed here: [Any way to get a Brother HL-L2320D to work with current Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966106/any-way-to-get-a-brother-hl-l2320d-to-work-with-current-ubuntu)

Comment: This does happen sometimes (you need to remove and reinstall the drivers). I have noticed that my brother printer also likes to be on the same USB port every time I use it.